# UIAlertView - retrieve textfield value from textfield added via code

Tags: iphone, xcode

Here is the code I have to create an UIAlertView with a textbox.

```
    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Enter A Username Here"     message:@"this gets covered!" 
                                               delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Dismiss" otherButtonTitles:@"OK!", nil];   
    UITextField *myTextField = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(12, 45, 260, 25)];

    CGAffineTransform myTransform = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(0, 60);
    [alert setTransform:myTransform];
    alert.tag = kAlertSaveScore;

    [myTextField setBackgroundColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
    [alert addSubview:myTextField];
    [alert show];
    [alert release];
    [myTextField release];
```

My question is, how do I get the value from the textfield in:

```
- (void) alertView:(UIAlertView *) actionSheet clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex {

}
```

I know I can get the standard stuff for the alertview such as actionSheet.tag and such, but how would I get the above created textfield?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
@interface MyClass {
    UITextField *alertTextField;
}

@end
```

And instead of declaring it locally, just use that.

```
    //...
    alertTextField = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(12, 45, 260, 25)];
    //...

- (void) alertView:(UIAlertView *) alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex {
    NSString *text = alertTextField.text;
    alertTextField = nil;
}
```

Answer (score 6):

Just give it a tag, and find it using the tag later. So, using your code:

```
UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Enter A Username Here"     message:@"this gets covered!" 
                                           delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Dismiss" otherButtonTitles:@"OK!", nil];   
UITextField *myTextField = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(12, 45, 260, 25)];

CGAffineTransform myTransform = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(0, 60);
[alert setTransform:myTransform];
alert.tag = kAlertSaveScore;

// Give the text field some unique tag
[myTextField setTag:10250];

[myTextField setBackgroundColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
[alert addSubview:myTextField];
[alert show];
[alert release];
[myTextField release];
```

Then, in the call-back, wherever that happens to be and without having to worry about memory management or state management of the text field:

```
- (void) alertView:(UIAlertView *) actionSheet clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
{
  // Get the field you added to the alert view earlier (you should also
  // probably validate that this field is there and that it is a UITextField but...)
  UITextField* myField = (UITextField*)[actionSheet viewWithTag:10250];
  NSLog(@"Entered text: %@", [myField text]);
}
```